# With python regex, only those match my pattern but NOT contains '='

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex. I'm using regex to match urls, some of the result contains `=`. I want only those url match my pattern but not contains `=`.

My pattern is `\S+google.com\/\S+-\S+`

For example:

1. MATCH:    `www.google.com/aa-bb`
2. NOT MATCH: `google.com/`
3. NOT MATCH: `www.google.com/aa-bb=cc`

My current pattern matches 1 and 3, but I want 1 ONLY

With this answer, [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word), I have tried `(?=((?!=).)*)(?=\S+google.com\/\S+-\S+)`, trying to intersect the result of both match. But it seems regex does not work this way.

Python Regex answers only, please. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far. You must show you have attempted something.

Answer (score 3):

Change `\S` to `[^\s=]` so it doesn't match spaces or `=`.

You should also anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`, so it has to match the entire URL. Otherwise it will match the `www.google.com/aa-bb` part of `www.google.com/aa-bb=cc`.

```
^\S+google\.com\/[^\s=]+-[^\s=]+$
```

You should also escape literal `.` in the regexp.

Comment: Also, OP has a mistake-  `.` should be escaped with a `\.`

Comment: Thanks! This works as I described! A follow-up question: what if I want to return only what before '='?

Comment: Then get rid of the `$` at the end. It will match as far as it can.